# Parallax Scrolling smoother

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I have implemented n Parallax Scrolling effect and did it without n framework or Plugin to be Flexible.

My code is really easy I just check in which section I am and then make the Background slower. But why is this so bad because if I scroll to fast it looks bad and stumbles around...

The pictures are loaded.

Here is the Live Example on my page at the bottom.

http://ingroups.de/home.php

Example of my Code:

```
$( window ).scroll(function() { 

var schonGescrollt = $(window).scrollTop(); 

//Wich Section
if(schonGescrollt>=0){

    //The Background slow Scroll
    var scrollLangsam = schonGescrollt*0.4;

    //The White Boxes wich scroll normal 
    var scrollNormal = schonGescrollt*0.6;

    $('#PARALLAX_bild1').css('margin-top', scrollLangsam);

    //The Picture scroll a little bit with the White box until the Picture is visbible
    if(schonGescrollt<=(heightProzent*125)){

        $('#PARALLAX_infoBox1').css('margin-top', -scrollNormal);
        if(scrollNormal<=(heightProzent*27)){

            $('#PARALLAX_bild2').css('margin-top', -scrollNormal);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: becouse mouse scroll on windows jump block of pixel so the image need to readact to the new jump everytime.

Answer (score 1):

1. Except Mozilla Firefox all Browsers are not scrolling smoothly. Thats a common flaw when using Parallax.
2. Optimizing your Pictures would help a lot. It takes them hours to load and they have much more quality then needed. ( I mean who is using a 4.950px × 3.300px Screen, even in Full HD they would be to big.)